# similar tools in Python? (tools from Ruby)

Tags: python, ruby

1. gem: package management.
2. bundler: dependency management
3. rspec: test framework.
4. watchr: autotest tool
5. yard: documentation tool.
6. rdoc Markdown: markdown for writing code's comment.
7. rvm: Ruby version Manager.
8. rake: task tool.

I want to find some tools in Python can do the job describe above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. gem == easy_install, a part of setuptools
2. setuptools
3. for testing framework see nosetest
4. [autonose](http://github.com/gfxmonk/autonose/tree/master)
5. epydoc or sphinx
6. use [docstrings](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)
7. [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) along with [virtualenvwrapper](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/).
8. [paver](http://www.blueskyonmars.com/projects/paver/)

Comment: setuptools doesn't actually do what bundler does. nosetest does not do BDD like rspec does.

Comment: Yes and vice versa. This is a "closest match".

Answer (score 1):

1) PyPI/setuptools/distribute

2) done via setuptools (install_requires directive in setup.py)

3) unittest/unittest/nose (with integration in Hudson or Buildbot)

5) Sphinx

http://pypi.python.org/pypi

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools

https://www.sphinx-doc.org